# What is the return type of a Java exception?

Tags: java, exception, methods, calculator

I'm writing a Calculator exercise that takes an array of int for addition, subtraction, division and multiplication. I need to check in every method that the array is not null. Instead of repeating myself, can I write the throwException method once and then just call it in my method?
e.g. for addition

```
public int addAll(int[] integers) {
    throwExceptionForNullArray();
    int sumOfAllIntegers = 0;
    for (int integer : integers) {
        sumOfAllIntegers += integer;
    }
    return  sumOfAllIntegers;
}

public throwExceptionForNullArray (int[] integers){
    if (integers == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty array is not allowed");
    }
}
```

But Java requires a return type in a method, do you have any ideas that can make the throwExceptionForNullArray method work? What should be the return type?
Thank you

Comment: Thrown exception are not returned... but thrown (they do not "count" to the return type of a method). Thus, since the method does not normally return anything, its return type should be `void`.

Comment: A remark: method `throwExceptionForNullArray(...)` is declared with a paramter of type `int[]`, but called with no parameter. We need to pass an `int[]` on the calling side to this method.

Comment: Aside from your question: message in `IllegalArgumentException("Empty array is not allowed")` is not valid. The `null` represents that there was *no* array provided (`null` was used *instead of any array*), not that provided array was empty (like `int[] emptyArray = {};`). Difference is like getting empty box and not getting a box at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the return type of a Java exception?

That's like asking: "What is the colour of ennui?" - the question doesn't make sense.

Let me put it differently. Imagine this hypothetical method:

```java
public int hello() {
  while (true) {
    // just loop forever and ever and ever.
  }
}
```

The above will... actually compile. Try it!

That's a bit odd - this method is declared to return an int, and yet, the method *contains no `return` statement at all*. And yet this compiles fine. That's because it is a bit wonky in how it 'works'. It never actually exits, so there's no violation of the rules here. A return type of `int` means: *If* this method returns normally, it *must* do so by returning an `int` value.

Note, *if* it returns normally. There is no rule stating that all methods must necessarily always return normally, or that it could ever even return normally. The above method cannot return normally, for example.

A "normal" return occurs when your method hits a `return` statement, or just gets to the closing brace.

A throw statement is an abnormal condition. A method that exits by way of throwing **does not return anything**. It got out by throwing. That doesn't mean it "returned" the exception. It means it "threw" the exception.

A method that cannot possibly return normally (and if all ways through the method end in a `throw` statement, it cannot possibly return normally) can pick whatever it wants for a return type. It just won't matter. Anything will do. For a method whose stated purpose is:

- If the inputs are valid, do absolutely nothing
- Otherwise, throw an exception highlighting what's invalid about the input

The usual return type is `void`. So, do that:

```java
public void checkInput(int[] integers) {
    if (integers == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("integers");
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- Your message was dead wrong. `null` does not mean "empty", a very important distinction. `new int[0]` is an empty array. `null` is a null pointer. Don't conflate the two. It's possible to have a method that doesn't like an input of an empty array. In that case, the correct act to take is something like:

```java
if (integers.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty 'integers' array not allowed");
```

It's more appropriate to use NullPointerException for params being null when as a precondition they aren't supposed to be.

- If you're dereferencing the parameter, there's really no need to do this. The JVM itself will throw the NPE for you and even name it assuming you're using a modern JVM. You dereference `integers` (`for (int i : integers)` will do that), so you can remove it all and get the same result, namely: Calling that method with `null` will throw an NPE whose message includes the text 'integers'.
- Naming a method 'throwExceptionFor' is a bit too on the nose, it describes too much how it works and not enough what it is supposed to do. `checkInput` describes the why/what instead of the how, that's usually the better way to name methods.

Comment: Surely ennui is grey in colour?